# Automate update of models based on conditions

Tags: python, django

I have a model

```
class Session(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateField()
    startTime = models.TimeField()
```

The active field is set based on the date and start time.
For eg -

Suppose during the creation of an object, the date is for tomorrow, and let there be any time, I want to know the process and not the code on how and what to study to make this object active on that particular date and time.

BY default the active field is False, or should I change the way I'm thinking to implement it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to use a `DateTimeField` for the start timestamp, and make `active` a property, so:

```
from django.utils import timezone


class Session(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    
    @property
    def active(self):
        return timezone.now() >= self.start
```

This will thus *not* store the `active` field in the database, but simply determine the value when needed.

Comment: I thought to push the data to the front end upon being active, but now I'm going to simply pull active sessions from the front end.. and also remove the active field. Thanks :)